# batch convert videos to gifs in ffmpeg

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, terminal, gif

I want to batch convert mov to gif using ffmpeg on **MacOS**. Here is a script I use:

```
for i in *.mov; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -i palette256.png -loop -1 -lavfi paletteuse -r 20 “${i%.*}.gif"; done
```

But it doesn't work, [here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDx3S.jpg) and I have to stop the command using *"control + C"*

What should I change to make it work?

Comment: Inline the image. Add echo to the command while you are having issues. Then try several of the shown ffmpeg commands

Comment: Replace the fancy quote with a normal quote. See #2 in answer to duplicate question for more info.